# How to extract the 4 digit numbers using a regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract all the numbers after the `company_id:` part and store in a variable. My string looks the following.

```
String company ="{\"company_id\":4100\"data\" \"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135\"company_id\":3070,\"data\",\"company_id\":4061,\"data\"}"
```

In this case, the regex would extract numbers **4100**, **3070** and **4061**. I have many other numbers on my string, I just did not include them to save space. The numbers I want will be the only ones with 4 digits and will always come after the `company_id:` part. I tried the following

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(company);
```

However, that only returns the first digit and not the other two.

Comment: Add anchors on the ends. backslash b for boundaries. `\\b\\d{4}\\b`

Comment: You omitted the code where you use the matcher. That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: "However, that only returns the first digit and not the other two." Not according to this: https://ideone.com/xr5Yhq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve all the company ids using the regex `\"company_id\":(\\d{4})`. This makes sure that you only get the numbers after the `"company_id"` element. It captures it in a group.

```
String company ="{\"company_id\":4100\"data\" \"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135\"company_id\":3070,\"data\",\"company_id\":4061,\"data\"}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"company_id\":(\\d{4})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(company);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String companyId = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(companyId);
}
```

It seems that your String is not valid JSON so you can't use a JSON parser.

In your code, you only retrieve the first id because you problably didn't loop on all the matches.

Comment: If it was a valid  JSON String. How would you use the JSON parser. Thank you

Comment: @danilo If it were valid JSON, you could use Google GSON library for example to parse it. Take a look at [GSON user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Answer (score 0):

If the 4-digit number are always going to appear right after "company_id", then you could use this "company_id:[0-9]{4}" regex pattern to match all instances.